# EF giving me error in Production and not Dev.

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following connection string that is used by a generated EF model.  It works correctly on my local machine but when I deploy, I get the error below.  I have look at the URL referenced many time on SO:  http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/ and if it has the answer in it, I don't see it for my case.

I'm pasting the error below

```
  <add name="svcodecampEntitiesAllTables" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFModel.ModelAllTables.csdl|res://*/EFModel.ModelAllTables.ssdl|res://*/EFModel.ModelAllTables.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=svcc;integrated security=True;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Unable to load the specified metadata resource.","exceptionType":"System.Data.MetadataException","stackTrace":"   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor(String originalPath, String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)\r\n   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()\r\n   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)\r\n   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n   at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)\r\n   at WebAPI.rest.AttendeesDashboardController.Get(String userSearch, Nullable`1 presentersOnly, Nullable`1 currentCodeCampYearOnly, Nullable`1 start, Nullable`1 limit) in c:\\VCProject\\SVCodeCampWeb\\WebAPI\\rest\\AttendeesDashboardController.cs:line 97\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem too. I fixed it by explicitly naming the assembly that contains the model.

So, if your model is in "Product.DAL.dll", instead of:

```
  metadata=res://*/EFModel.ModelAllTables.csdl|...
```

put:

```
  metadata=res://Product.DAL/EFModel.ModelAllTables.csdl|...
```

for all 3 metadata resources

Comment: My model is below. Not exactly sure what to replace * with.

Comment: note sure what to replace.  My model:namespace WebAPI.EFModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class svcodecampEntitiesAllTables : DbContext
    {
        public svcodecampEntitiesAllTables()

Comment: This blog post explains ( in great detail! ) [`Troubleshooting Entity Framework Connection Strings`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/)

Comment: Hi Nicholas.  That reference you give is exactly the same reference that I mention at the top of my question saying I have looked at that and it did not help me.

Comment: oops - sorry! You need to replace the `*`s with the name of the assembly that contains your model `.edmx` file - not the namespace, although they may be the same. Try it on your dev machine first to make sure you've got it right.

Comment: my bad.  the article did solve my problem.  It got me to look at a web deployment config file that was not updating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must add reference to your project that contains the edmx diagram and change the connection string in the Nunit project

Change

```
<add name="ContainerName" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Diagram.csdl|re.....
```

By the name of the library in the 3 places in the metadata

```
<add name="ContainerName"connectionString="metadata=res://File.Data/Diagram.csdl|res://File.Data/Diagra...
```

"File.Data" is File.Data.dll, library generated by the project that contains the diagram

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and solved by running custom tool. Right click on Model.tt file and click on run custom tool and repeat the same for context.tt file and Model.edmx file. Rebuilding the application will works.